# How to display my comment count in the wordpress admin bar?

Tags: functions, admin, dashboard

Ok, so when I'm logged in, the above admin bar show's zero. Even though I did wrote 5 comments:

[image]

Is there a code to add in fuctions.php to display the correct number of comments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing in the admin bar is Pending comments.

Without building your own custom admin bar item there isn't any way to change this easily.